# pre-configure (default settings) for new shopping cart price rules in magento admin panel, or to prevent options from showing

Tags: magento

for our store, we often create catalog price rules (coupons) for customers using the same settings every time. The people using the admin panel to do this are not always technically-minded. Irrespective of that, it is of course possible for anyone to make a mistake and accidentally mis-configure a new coupon. How can we prevent this?

For instance -- we ALWAYS want these coupons to NOT show up in the rss feed (this could be bad if one slips through and if a sneaky customer knows to monitor the RSS feed). We also will NEVER want to use the setting for "fixed amount discount" -- it will ALWAYS be "fixed amount discount for whole cart", so it would be best if we could prevent "fixed amount discount" from even showing up in the list, or perhaps to force an "are you sure?" checkbox to appear next to "fixed amount discount" would be more appropriate. We have already had one coupon created by a new employee who accidentally used "fixed amount discount", giving a customer $120 in discounts on 12 items when it was only supposed to be $10 total. It was a hassle and awkward to tell that customer that it was unintentional.

Perhaps with coupons, it is more elegant to just buy a coupon plugin of some kind (and I will), but generally speaking, how are these sorts of things edited for creation of new things in the admin panel, such as new products, new categories. We don't necessarily want to go and create defaults for templates in xml, but rather we want the admin panel pages to perhaps have defaults already selected, or to prevent certain options from being visible, or to add "are you sure" checkboxes for certain options to force the user to double-check their work. Which files are to be edited for this?
Your comments are much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You would have to go into the backend and delete some of the code that shows these options. Magento is pretty good on when it comes to standardized problems, but this is a custom configuration and your ganna need to change the code to do it. The files should be under design/adminhtml and in the catalog section.